# ElasticSearch Error : Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition kafka issue

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Mine is a springboot application.There are kafka-consumers in my elastic-search code. So, while consuming events from kafka, getting error : "Unknown error fetching for topic partition ".

Ive checked the spring-kafka(1.7.7) and elastic versions(5.6.3). I tried incrementing spring-kafka version to 1.2.0. still facing same issue. This error is very recent. Did not change any code. It used to work fine for months. Problem is, it accepts few events and throws following error.

Error Log:

```
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:22.396 [ticket-listener-0-L-1] com.services.ElasticSearchBatchService postBulkRequest 151 - No messages to write
to elastic search.
[DEBUG] 2019-06-07 16:26:22.432 [conversation-listener-0-L-1] com.services.ElasticSearchBatchService postBulkRequest 156 - Bulk request to
ok 91 ms.
[INFO ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.673 [ticket-listener-0-L-1] com.listeners.TicketingEventKafkaListener ticketingEventListener 59 - Received eve
nts :1
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.674 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-4
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.675 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-0
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.676 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-3
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.676 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-1
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.677 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-2
[WARN ] 2019-06-07 16:26:40.677 [ticket-listener-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher parseFetchedData 723 - Unknown error fetching da
ta for topic-partition ticket_events_6221-5
```

Comment: post code, there is no way to help you without parts of code

Comment: which client version of kafka consumer are u using?

Comment: 1.1.7 spring kafka